# Doesn't append to the list

Tags: python, list, return, append

I've written a simple search function. created an empty list as well to have the results.

```
def simple_search(path,filename) :
    found_files = []
    try:
        folders = next(os.walk(path))[1]
        for i in next(os.walk(path))[2]:
            if filename in i:
                print(path+i)
                found_files.append(path+i)
        for folder in folders:
                folder_path = path + '\\' + folder
                simple_search(folder_path, filename)     
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    return found_files
```

The code doesn't append anything to the list and function returns an empty list.
The print statement (print(path+i)) works so there doesn't seem to be any problem with if condition.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you doing `next(os.walk(path))`

Comment: And why are you manually trying to use recursion to walk the directory? `os.walk` *already does this*. Can you explain in your own word what you are trying to do?

Comment: Besides the bugs listed above, I was able to get a file appended to the list running this on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

**Your issue** is that you ignore the return value when you recursively call `simple_search(folder_path, filename)` within `simple_search`. You could change the line to:

```py
findings = simple_search(folder_path, filename)
found_files.extend(findings)  # adds the values of the iterable (list in this case)
```

**However**, as juanpa.arrivillaga already pointed out in his comment, [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) does already iterate through the sub directories.

> Generate the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. (https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)

```py
import os

def simple_search(path, filename) :
    
    found_files = []

    for root, _, files in os.walk(path):

        for file in files:
            if filename in file:
                full_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                # print(full_path)
                found_files.append(full_path)

    return found_files

found_files = simple_search(r"D:\projects\test\data", "test.csv")
print(found_files)
```

---

Instead of using `os.walk`, you could also just use [`Path.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob). This makes your code more concise and easier to maintain:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def simple_search(path, filename):  # theoretically, you don't even need a function
    return [str(p) for p in Path(path).glob(f"**/*{filename}*")]

found_files = simple_search(r"D:\projects\test\data", "test.csv")
print(found_files)
```

---

**Advice:** Please try to avoid *unnecessary* recursion. Recursion always adds complexity to the code which can be hard to maintain and debug.